# SQL Cases Group By's Pivots Aggregates headache

Tags: sql-server

After a lot of looking into lots of various SQL syntax I'm still coming up short.

I have a table where the data is stored as such:

```
LineNumber     Date            JobNumber      Task          Hours
------------------------------------------------------------------
 1             2016-08-15      100            Task 1          0.5
 1             2016-08-16      100            Task 1          2.0
 2             2016-08-15      200            Task 2          4.0
 3             2016-08-16      200            Task 3          1.5
 4             2016-08-17      200            Task 6          3.5
```

What I am after doing is formatting the results so they look like this:

```
LineNumber      JobNumber        Task      Monday     Tuesday    Wednesday
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1               100              Task 1      0.5        2.0         0.0
2               200              Task 2      4.0        0.0         0.0
3               200              Task 3      0.0        1.5         0.0
4               200              Task 6      0.0        0.0         3.5
```

Using CASE statements I can get close. It's just the grouping that lets me down. Because I need the Tasks to group but they won't because they have unique dates and hours values.

Using this:

```
DECLARE @UserID int;
DECLARE @StartDate date;
DECLARE @MondayDate date;
DECLARE @TuesdayDate date;
DECLARE @WednesdayDate date;
DECLARE @ThursdayDate date;
DECLARE @FridayDate date;
DECLARE @SaturdayDate date;
DECLARE @SundayDate date;

SET @UserID = '1';
SET @StartDate = '2016-08-15';
SET @MondayDate = @StartDate;
SET @TuesdayDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @StartDate);
SET @WednesdayDate = DATEADD(DAY, 2, @StartDate);
SET @ThursdayDate = DATEADD(DAY, 3, @StartDate);
SET @FridayDate = DATEADD(DAY, 4, @StartDate);
SET @SaturdayDate = DATEADD(DAY, 5, @StartDate);
SET @SundayDate = DATEADD(DAY, 6, @StartDate);

select LineNumber, JobNumber, JobName, Task,
Monday = (CASE WHEN Date = @MondayDate THEN Hours ELSE '0.0' END),
Tuesday = (CASE WHEN Date = @TuesdayDate THEN Hours ELSE '0.0' END),
Wednesday = (CASE WHEN Date = @WednesdayDate THEN Hours ELSE '0.0' END),
Thursday = (CASE WHEN Date = @ThursdayDate THEN Hours ELSE '0.0' END),
Friday = (CASE WHEN Date = @FridayDate THEN Hours ELSE '0.0' END),
Saturday = (CASE WHEN Date = @SaturdayDate THEN Hours ELSE '0.0' END),
Sunday = (CASE WHEN Date = @SundayDate THEN Hours ELSE '0.0' END)

From v_TimesheetDataLines

WHERE Date >= @MondayDate and Date <= @SundayDate and UserID = @UserID
Order By LineNumber asc
```

I can get close but I still end up with ungrouped rows where the task and job number are the same.

My results at present are like this:

```
LineNumber      JobNumber        Task      Monday     Tuesday    Wednesday
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1               100              Task 1     0.5        0.0       0.0
1               100              Task 1     0.0        2.0       0.0
2               200              Task 2     4.0        0.0       0.0
3               200              Task 3     0.0        1.5       0.0
4               200              Task 6     0.0        0.0       3.5
```

So its the 2 lines that are both to be line 1 in the final results that I need to group. They would always have the same Job Number and Task.

I have tried various CASE and nested SELECTS but can't quite get there. I found a few other posts on here regarding pivots which I think might be a solution. Unfortunately I'm struggling to get my head around those statements and exactly how to use them.

Any answers\help greatly appreciated as ever.

Comment: Please show expected output

Comment: Hi Game, second code block shows what I am after the output being. Basically it needs to group by the LineNumber, JobNumber and Task.

Answer (score 0):

Use GROUP BY over LineNumber, JobNumber and Task.
Use MAX (or SUM) over the weekdays.

**Edit:**

Like [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6250e/9)

Comment: Hi Andy, using aggregate on the weekdays means that I only ever get the largest, smallest or sum of the hours column. I need the values to remain as they are.

Comment: @DA082 - it would only aggregate values if they were on the same task, on the same day.  I assumed your desired behaviour was 1 row per task.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/51755/2

Answer (score 0):

For your consideration:

Just a side note, You could add UserID in the Group By parameter and do all in one shot.

```
Exec [prc-Pivot] 'Select * from YourData','DateName(WEEKDAY,Date)','sum(Hours)[]','LineNumber,JobNumber','count(*)[Records]'
```

Returns

```
LineNumber  JobNumber   Records Monday    Tuesday   Wednesday
1           100         2       0.50      2.00      0.00
2           200         1       4.00      0.00      0.00
3           200         1       0.00      1.50      0.00
4           200         1       0.00      0.00      3.50
```

The Stored Procedure for Dynamic Pivots

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prc-Pivot] (
    @Source varchar(1000),          -- Any Table or Select Statement
    @PvotCol varchar(250),          -- Field name or expression ie. Month(Date)
    @Summaries varchar(250),        -- aggfunction(aggValue)[optionalTitle]
    @GroupBy varchar(250),          -- Optional additional Group By 
    @OtherCols varchar(500) )       -- Optional Group By or aggregates
AS

--Exec [prc-Pivot] 'Select Year=Year(TR_Date),* From [Chinrus-Series].[dbo].[DS_Treasury_Rates]','''Q''+DateName(QQ,TR_Date)','avg(TR_Y10)[-Avg]','Year','count(*)[Records],min(TR_Y10)[Min],max(TR_Y10)[Max],Avg(TR_Y10)[Avg]'
--Exec [prc-Pivot] '#Temp','Attribute','max(Description)[]','ID','count(*)[Records]'

Set NoCount On

Declare @Vals varchar(max),@SQL varchar(max);
Set @Vals = ''
Set @OtherCols= IsNull(', ' + @OtherCols,'')
Set @Source = case when @Source Like 'Select%' then @Source else 'Select * From '+@Source end
Create Table #TempPvot  (Pvot varchar(100))
Insert Into #TempPvot
Exec ('Select Distinct Convert(varchar(100),' + @PvotCol + ') as Pvot FROM (' + @Source + ') A')
Select @Vals = @Vals + ', isnull(' + Replace(Replace(@Summaries,'(','(CASE WHEN ' + @PvotCol + '=''' + Pvot +  ''' THEN '),')[', ' END),0) As [' + Pvot ) From #TempPvot Order by Pvot
Drop Table #TempPvot
Set @SQL = Replace('Select ' + Isnull(@GroupBy,'') + @OtherCols + @Vals + ' From (' + @Source + ') PvtFinal ' + case when Isnull(@GroupBy,'')<>'' then 'Group By ' + @GroupBy + ' Order by ' + @GroupBy else '' end,'Select , ','Select ')
--Print @SQL
Exec (@SQL)
```

**

> **EDIT- To Add Parameters**

**

```
Declare @MondayDate Date = '2016-08-15'
Declare @SundayDate Date = '2016-08-21'
Declare @UserID int =  1
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = 'Select * from YourTable Where Date>='''+cast(@MondayDate as varchar(10))+''' and Date<='''+cast(@SundayDate as varchar(10))+''' and UserID='+cast(@UserID as varchar(25))

Exec [prc-Pivot] @SQL,'DateName(WEEKDAY,Date)','sum(Hours)[]','LineNumber,JobNumber','count(*)[Records]'
```

Not sure what version of SQL Server, but Concat would be my choice when building the SQL String

Comment: Hi John, This almost works except I need to specify a range of dates as part of the select statement. When I do that I get an error "Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int"